# Showing two same datas on datagrid

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008-r2

[SOLVED], gzaxx's answer.

Even though in the database a member is not inserted two times, in the datagrid it is showing two times!
I have this Form that I add members, and another Form where I add member's payments. When I add more than 1 payment to a member, that members shows two times in the grid.

To List Members I'm using this:

```
        public List<Member> ListMembers()
        {
            List<Member> Members = new List<Member>();


            string STATUS = "SELECT m.Id, m.Name,m.Surname, m.EntryDate, p.EndDay FROM Members m left join Payments p on m.Id = p.MemberId order by m.Id ";
            using (sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString_WORK))
            {
                sqlConnection.Open();

                using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(STATUS, sqlConnection))
                {
                    var sqlReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

                    while (sqlReader.Read())
                    {
                        var member = new Member
                        {
                            Id = Convert.ToInt32(sqlReader["Id"]),
                            Name = sqlReader["Name"].ToString(),
                            Surname = sqlReader["Surname"].ToString(),
                            EntryDate = Convert.ToDateTime(sqlReader["EntryDate"])
                        };

                        if (sqlReader["EndDay"].ToString() != "")
                        if (Convert.ToDateTime(sqlReader["EndDay"]) < DateTime.Today)
                        {
                            member.Status = Status.Unpaid.ToString();
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            member.Status = Status.Paid.ToString();
                        }

                        Members.Add(member);
                    }
                }
            }

            return Members;
        }
```

For Payments :

```
        public List<Payment> ListPayments(Payment entity)
        {
            List<Payment> Payments = new List<Payment>();

            string SELECT = "SELECT * FROM Payments WHERE MemberId = @MemberId";

            using (sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString_WORK))
            {
                sqlConnection.Open();

                using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(SELECT, sqlConnection))
                {
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@MemberId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = entity.MemberId;

                    var sqlReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

                    while (sqlReader.Read())
                    {
                        var payment = new Payment
                        {
                            Id = Convert.ToInt32(sqlReader["Id"]),
                            MemberId = Convert.ToInt32(sqlReader["MemberId"]),
                            Amount = Convert.ToDecimal(sqlReader["Amount"]),
                            StartDay = Convert.ToDateTime(sqlReader["StartDay"]),
                            EndDay = Convert.ToDateTime(sqlReader["EndDay"])
                        };

                        Payments.Add(payment);
                    }
                }
            }

            return Payments;
        }
```

If a members doesn't have a payment, it will show NOTHING to it's Status column. If a members have ONE payment, it will show its status. But if I add a NEW payment (more than ONE), data grid will show the same member equal to its payments on the grid. What Am I doing wrong ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query:

```
SELECT m.Id, m.Name,m.Surname, m.EntryDate, p.EndDay FROM Members m left join Payments p on m.Id = p.MemberId order by m.Id
```

will return a member with (if found) all `Payment.EndDay` records matched with given member. So if you only want one row (and maybe the latest payment) then your query should look like this:

```
SELECT m.Id, m.Name,m.Surname, m.EntryDate, MAX(p.EndDay) as EndDay
FROM Members m left join Payments p on m.Id = p.MemberId
GROUP BY m.Id, m.Name,m.Surname, m.EntryDate
order by m.Id
```

Comment: This shows only one member so it's fixed in a way.. BUT.. it doesn't get the last payment. :\

Comment: It gets latest `EndDay`. Is latest payemnt equal to the one that has it `EndDay` latest?

Comment: Oh, it's okay! I wasn't checking if there is a date already BIGGER (don't know the right word to say it) than the date I'm registering. It works perfect. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

it is how left join works. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

the values being doubled is caused by "join" - there is as many records returned as there are payments. grouping them, as @gzaxx suggested may be a good idea

if there is null in column where there's no payment, depending on what database you're using, you can remedy that using ISNULL (mssql) (http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp) command in your query.